# Is it possible to upload images to facebook app via Graph API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, photos

[On this page](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/515/#video_upload) it is described how to upload videos to an application on facebook via Graph API.
I would like to know if the same is possible for images, i.e. is it possible to create application albums and uploading images to it using Graph API?
I know it's possible to create user albums, but I want the photos to "belong" to the application, so they are not shown in the users albums, but administered in the application.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think you can upload videos “to an application” any more – you can only do that for user profiles or pages. (Apps do not automatically have an associated page any more, you have to create it yourself from the app settings section).

But of course you can upload photos to a page, in the same way you can do it for a user profile.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#photos, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/